# Issues using a left join and case when statement to update a column in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have a use case where I am trying to update a specific column in a table with values from another table. This could be done using `UPDATE` statement but DBT does not support `UPDATE` statement, so I am trying to write a `LEFT JOIN` with a `CASE WHEN` statement to achieve the same result, but I have been experiencing increased number of records based on the left join.

Table 1: sorted

| time_stamp | Callsign | filename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23/02/2024 04:12:53 | BQw23T | lex.txt |
| 23/02/2024 05:32:56 |  | lex.txt |
| 23/02/2024 05:06:56 | BQw23T | lem.txt |
| 23/02/2024 06:12:59 |  | lem.txt |

and table 2: minmax

| min_timestamp | Callsign | filename | max_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23/02/2024 04:12:56 | BQw24T | lex.txt | 23/02/2024 04:55:56 |
| 23/02/2024 05:00:56 | BQw24T | lex.txt | 23/02/2024 07:00:56 |
| 23/02/2024 05:55:56 | BQw23T | lem.txt | 23/02/2024 07:00:56 |
| 23/02/2024 06:00:56 | BQw23T | lem.txt | 23/02/2024 06:40:56 |

I am trying to get this result:

| time_stamp | Callsign | filename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23/02/2024 04:12:53 | BQw23T | lex.txt |
| 23/02/2024 05:32:56 | BQw24T | lex.txt |
| 23/02/2024 05:06:56 | BQw23T | lem.txt |
| 23/02/2024 06:12:59 | BQw23T | lem.txt |

So in essence I am trying to join sorted table with the minmax table using a left join when filename of sorted and filename of mimax are matching, and the timestamp in sorted is between minmax min_timestamp and max_timestamp. if these are matching I would update  sorted Callsign with minmax callsign. but the problem is sometimes we have more than one match so the idea is to pick the first match and use it for the update. I wonder if I can be pointed in the right direction

```
SELECT
    s.time_stamp,
    CASE
        WHEN m.callsign IS NOT NULL THEN m.callsign
        ELSE s.callsign
    END AS Callsign,
    s.filename
FROM
    Sorted s
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
         s.filename,
         s.time_stamp,
         m.callsign
     FROM
         Sorted s
     LEFT JOIN 
         Minmax m ON s.filename = m.filename
                  AND s.time_stamp BETWEEN m.min_timestamp AND m.max_timestamp
     QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.filename, s.time_stamp ORDER BY m.min_timestamp) = 1
    ) m ON s.filename = m.filename AND s.time_stamp = m.time_stamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than one match, fill the null callsign from sorted with the one from minmax from all matching data. Doesn't matter if there are going to be a lot of rows at this point.

Because after that, do the sorting and filter the row number = 1 only.

```
WITH cte as ( 
    select 
        s.timestamp,
        coalesce(m.callsign, s.callsign) callsign,
        s.filename,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY s.filename, s.time_stamp 
            ORDER BY coalesce(m.min_timestamp, s.timestamp)
        ) rn
    from sorted s
    left join minmax m
    ON s.filename = m.filename
    AND s.time_stamp BETWEEN m.min_timestamp AND m.max_timestamp
    AND m.callsign is not null
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```